# How should one interpret a double slash, //?

Tags: notation

Example usage I've seen: $x^2 / (y // z)$

Context: I recently started learning some fundamental electrical engineering, where I saw

> I calculated the power doing $vs² / (r1 + ron + ron // ron+r2)$

Comment: Where did you see it? Can you give more context? e.g. if you found this in a `python` program, the `//` operator would mean to divide then round down to the nearest integer. e.g. `3//2 == 1`.

Comment: It's electrical engineering related, not programming. I've updated my question. :)

Comment: http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_1/chpt_7/2.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In an electrical engineering context, I would guess that $a // b$ probably means the equivalent single resistance for 2 resistors in parallel of size $a$ and $b$, which is $\frac{ab}{a+b}$.

Comment: This is also backed up by @pedja's comment to the question. Thanks.